# dynamic_cast to interface won't compile

Tags: c++-cli

I have some C# code like this:

```
string GetString(int n, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    T value = data[n];
    IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;
    if (formattable != null)
        return formattable.ToString(null, cultureInfo)
    return value.ToString();
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in a C++ generic class:

```
String^ GetString(int n, CultureInfo^ cultureInfo)
{
    T value = data[n];
    IFormattable^ formattable = dynamic_cast<IFormattable^>(value);
    if (formattable != nullptr)
        return formattable->ToString(nullptr, cultureInfo);
    return value->ToString();
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get:

```
error C2681: 'T': invalid expression type for dynamic_cast
```

I'm not sure why it won't compile as I was under the understanding that dynamic_cast was similar to the as operator in C#

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone mention that there are issues with generics and dynamic_cast in another post, and was able to figure it out.

I was thinking the problem was with IFormattable, but the problem is with 'value'.

It compiles fine and works if I cast the value to Object^ first:

```
String^ GetString(int n, CultureInfo^ cultureInfo)
{
    T value = data[n];
    IFormattable^ formattable = dynamic_cast<IFormattable^>((Object^)value);
    if (formattable != nullptr)
        return formattable->ToString(nullptr, cultureInfo);
    return value->ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast<>`, it behaves like the *as* operator.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Is this doing the same thing underneath as `dynamic_cast<>((Object^)val)`? Is there a benefit to using one over the other in this scenario? I read the MSDN docs on it, but I am still not quite sure about the differences in behavior.